# Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed

Tags: macos, proxy, homebrew, macos-mojave

I ran `brew update` and got

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': Failed to connect to 10.8.0.1 port 8080: Operation timed out
>
> Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core failed!

So I sometimes use a network which has proxy, so I added the following lines to .bash_profile (apart from usual changes in network settings via system preferences):

> export http_proxy="http://10.8.0.1:8080"
>
> export https_proxy="https://10.8.0.1:8080"

So I thought this might be causing the problem and commented these lines out, used source .bash_profile, rebooted and used cellular network. Still the same error.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First remove the proxy, if you are using any proxy.
I had the same problem.

In your terminal try running `brew update-reset` and then `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Just doing `brew update-reset` fixed this for me.  As a call out, it took a long time for this to run, so be patient.

Comment: `brew update-reset` made the trick. Took like 10 seconds to run.

Answer (score 2):

Reverting changes to `~/.gitconfig` worked for me.
From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64409020/1762493

> The solution provided by OP is certainly a valid workaround, but for more context, the full piece of Git configuration that caused this behavior likely looked something like this:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

☝️ This is the part I commented out for `brew update` to work again.