# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) when doing a brew cask install "program"

Tags: macos, github, homebrew, permission-denied

Whenever I try to do a git clone, or a brew install I get the following error:

Not sure what the issue is and I am using ohmysh

```
==> Tapping homebrew/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask` exited with 128.
Follow the instructions here:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask#reporting-bugs
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils.rb:266:in `safe_system'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/tap.rb:273:in `install'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:157:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/cmd.rb:123:in `run'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/cask.rb:9:in `cask'
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:103:in `<main>'
```

Comment: in Catalina osx you have to allow it from privacy & security

Comment: is your disk full, and are your directories writeable? what is the output when you run `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask mydir`? I'm interested to see if the message is different for HTTP rather than SSH.

Comment: @MoriBellamy, sorry about the delay. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer was in my .gitconfig file.

Had to comment out this line:

```
#   insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution provided by OP is certainly a valid workaround, but for more context, the full piece of Git configuration that caused this behavior likely looked something like this:

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

This has the effect of forcing any GitHub requests made over HTTPS to instead use SSH. The `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)` notice indicates that you are not set up to use SSH via GitHub.

For some additional background/discussion:

- [Homebrew community discussion answer](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/cannot-install-homebrew-permissions-denied/7910/6)
- [Homebrew GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/52)

The [GitHub docs on Authenticating with GitHub from Git](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/set-up-git#next-steps-authenticating-with-github-from-git) recommend connecting over HTTPS, so if you're fine with that, you can remove the original lines of configuration.

If you would prefer to always connect over SSH, you can keep the configuration as is, and follow the instructions on [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).